# Usage of "I am afraid"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, word-order, subjects, dependent-clause

What kind of sentence should follow the phrase "I am afraid", assertive or interogative?
For example, is the following sentence grammatical?

> I am afraid is it appropriate ask me a copy of it.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. I think you will find that questions of this sort are readily answered with a good dictionary, such as the [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/afraid); if that leaves you in any doubt, you may click on the *edit* link above to revise your question, citing what you find in the dictionary and addressing more specific issues. You may also find that this question is better suited to [ell.SE]; if so, you may click on the *flag* link above and ask that a moderator migrate it.

Answer (score 1):

*(Be) Afraid* is a psychological predicate adjective (a "psych-predicate" in the trade) referring to emotions experienced by the subject of the predicate (here, ***I***).

There are a **lot** of psych-predicates in English; many look like passives because they use predicate adjectives that are either formed or indistinguishable from past participles. However, they're not passives, because they don't normally take a *by*-phrase to express agent, but rather a noun or a clause of some sort that refers to the cause of the emotion; the noun or clause may well use a preposition, but it won't be *by*.

E.g, to mention only synonymous predicates (which use *of*),

- *He is afraid/frightened/scared.*
- *??He is afraid/frightened/scared by Mr. Lloyd.*
  (*frightened* and *scared* are OK as passives, too, but they they refer to an event, not an emotion)
- *He is afraid/frightened/scared that she'll catch him.*
- *He is afraid/frightened/scared to kiss her.*
- *He is afraid/frightened/scared of kissing her.*
- *He is afraid/frightened/scared of snakes.*

Psych-predicates require a human subject (or an anthropomorphized animal, thing, or concept), and often correlate with the words that the participial adjectives are formed from.

E.g, in this case

- *fear/feared/afraid*
- *fright/frighten/frightened/frightening*
- *scare/scared/scaredy/scary*

Some of these predicates take agent subjects and patient objects (*The tiger scared the mice*), while others take patient experiencer subjects and a prepositional phrase (*The tiger is scared of mice*), and there are other patterns as well.